# How to add reverse IP record by using DNSPython

Tags: dns, dnspython, bind9

I try to add DNS record by using DNSPython;

it works well when I set dns like this:

```
import dns.resolver
import dns.query
import dns.reversename
import dns.update
import dns.rdatatype

update = dns.update.Update('test.com')
update.replace('a', 3600, dns.rdatatype.A, '10.10.10.10')
response = dns.query.tcp(update, '127.0.0.1')
```

However it doesn't work when I set reverse dns by the same way:

```
update = dns.update.Update('10.in-addr.arpa')
update.replace('10.10.10.', 3600, dns.rdatatype.PTR, 'a.test.com')
response = dns.query.tcp(update, '127.0.0.1')
```

I want to know how to set reverse dns successfully, Thx~

Answer (score 1):

I find the problem:

```
update.replace('10.10.10.', 3600, dns.rdatatype.PTR, 'a.test.com')
```

this should be like this;

```
update.replace('10.10.10', 3600, dns.rdatatype.PTR, 'a.test.com')
```

But another problem is: This way to update reverse dns is not always successful, sometimes when I use 'nslookup' to test, it seems that it isn't added to dns server;

what's more, when I nslookup ip like:

```
nslookup 10.10.10.10
Server:         127.0.0.1
Address:        127.0.0.1#53

10.10.10.10.in-addr.arpa        name =a.test.com.10.in-addr.arpa.
```

This is not what I want, when using nsupdate to add, it only shows:

```
10.10.10.10.in-addr.arpa        name =a.test.com.
```

What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Encountered this issue myself.
You're missing a dot at the end of you name:

```
update.replace('10.10.10', 3600, dns.rdatatype.PTR, 'a.test.com**.**')
```

Answer (score -1):

You have issue with the '10.10.10' in the update.replace.
It needs to be FQDN - '10.10.10.10.in-addr.arpa'.
You can use something like this:

Get reverse IP

```
reventry = dns.reversename.from_address('10.10.10.10')
```

Define in-addr.arpa zone to update - I have .labels[3:] for A class subnet zone file (10.in-addr.arpa). If you have C class (10.10.10.in-addr.arpa) then use .labels[1:]

```
revzone = ''
revzone = '.'.join(dns.name.from_text(str(reventry)).labels[3:])
```

And add the action

```
raction = dns.update.Update(revzone)
raction.replace(reventry, 3600, dns.rdatatype.PTR, 'a.test.com')
```

This should work just fine.